# Sorting by date & time in descending order?

Tags: mysql, sql

all
         I want to display last 5 entered data for specific id.
My sql query is,

```
SELECT id, name, form_id, DATE(updated_at) as date
  FROM wp_frm_items
  WHERE user_id = 11 && form_id=9
  ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

`updated_at` is DATETIME

It displays last 5 entry sort by date not by time. On same date then it is sorting alphabetically.

Suppose i have 3 entries in same date with diff time

let's say

```
Ajay 1/3/2012 1:15
John 1/3/2012 1:00
Bony 1/3/2012 1:10
```

after querying the above query

what i got is

```
Ajay 1/3/2012 1:15
Bony 1/3/2012 1:10
John 1/3/2012 1:00
```

Sort by date then after alphabetically

What i want is this..

```
John 1/3/2012 1:00
Bony 1/3/2012 1:10
Ajay 1/3/2012 1:15
```

Sorted by date and time also...

Comment: What you say you want is not in descending order…

Comment: What is the definition of the column `updated_at`?

Comment: i want to short it by date and time too...

Comment: What datatype is updated_at ?

Comment: Can you add the table's definition? (so we see the datatypes)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you want the last 5 rows, ordered in ascending order, you need a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ( SELECT id, name, form_id, DATE(updated_at) AS updated_date, updated_at
      FROM wp_frm_items
      WHERE user_id = 11 
        AND form_id=9
      ORDER BY updated_at DESC
      LIMIT 5
    ) AS tmp
ORDER BY updated_at
```

---

After reading the question for 10th time, this may be (just maybe) what you want. Order by Date descending and then order by time (on same date) ascending:

```
SELECT id, name, form_id, DATE(updated_at) AS updated_date
FROM wp_frm_items
WHERE user_id = 11 
  AND form_id=9
ORDER BY DATE(updated_at) DESC
       , updated_at ASC
```

Comment: If that is what he wants, much better to reverse the result in the application rather than do that query right?

Comment: @MatthewScragg: With just 5 rows returned, I don't think it matters, both are ok.

Comment: See Last 5 or 10 is not an issue here issue is short by time too

Comment: I don't clearly understand why we need to add DATE(datefield) to an DateTime field... but it worked!

Answer (score 24):

putting the UNIX_TIMESTAMP will do the trick.

```
SELECT id, NAME, form_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at) AS DATE
    FROM wp_frm_items
    WHERE user_id = 11 && form_id=9
    ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT id, name, form_id, DATE(updated_at) as date
FROM wp_frm_items
WHERE user_id = 11 && form_id=9
ORDER BY date ASC
```

"DESC" stands for descending but you need ascending order ("ASC").

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM (
               SELECT id, name, form_id, DATE(updated_at) as date
               FROM wp_frm_items
               WHERE user_id = 11 && form_id=9
               ORDER BY updated_at DESC
             ) AS TEMP
    ORDER BY DATE(updated_at) DESC, name DESC
```

Give it a try.

Comment: @NoobASThreeDeveloper: No, it is not unnecessary. It is not only the date in the column, there is time also and in most of cases records can not have same date and time both. Therefore the step is needed

Comment: @Click: The step is indeed unnecessary. You don't need to wrap this in a subquery. A simple `ORDER BY DATE(updated_at) DESC, name DESC` would have the same result. Not to mention that the syntax you have is not valid SQL (despite that MySQL may allow it). In the external query, there is no `updated_at` and the `ORDER BY DATE(updated_at)` should result in an error.

Comment: @ypercube: If you do this records will not be sorted by the `TIME` as well. OP wants records to be sorted by date and time both not only the date

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to sort by date first then by names

```
SELECT id, name, form_id, DATE(updated_at) as date
  FROM wp_frm_items
  WHERE user_id = 11 && form_id=9
  ORDER BY updated_at DESC,name ASC
```

This will sort the records by date first, then by names

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the simplest ways to sort record by Date:

```
SELECT  `Article_Id` ,  `Title` ,  `Source_Link` ,  `Content` ,  `Source` , `Reg_Date`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `Reg_Date` ) AS DATE
FROM article
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Query works for me.
Database Tabel t_sonde_results has domain d_date (datatype DATE) and d_time (datatype TIME)
The intention is to query for last entry in t_sonde_results sorted by Date and Time

select * from
(select * from
(SELECT * FROM `t_sonde_results` WHERE d_user_name = 'kenis' and d_smartbox_id = 6 order by d_time asc)  AS tmp
order by d_date and d_time limit 1) as tmp1

Comment: Following Query works for me.
Database Tabel t_sonde_results has domain d_date (datatype DATE) and d_time (datatype TIME)
The intention is to query for last entry in t_sonde_results sorted by Date and Time


SELECT * FROM `t_sonde_results` WHERE d_user_name = 'kenis' and d_smartbox_id = 6 order by d_date desc, d_time desc limit 1

Answer (score -2):

I used a simpler solution found partly here:
[How to sort details with Date and time in sql server ?](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/694671/How-to-sort-details-with-Date-and-time-in-sql-serv)
I used this query to get my results:

`SELECT TOP (5) * FROM My_Table_Name WHERE id=WhateverValueINeed ORDER BY DateTimeColumnName DESC`

This is more straight forward and worked for me.

**Notice: the column of the Date has the "datetime" type**