# mySQL ORDER BY TODAY AND THEN NORMAL SORTING

Tags: mysql, sorting, datetime

How can I filter the dates that it would sort first by today then normal?

I have a column with data type datetime, I wanted my results to be sorted showing today's date first and continue normal sorting.

Comment: What does "normal" sorting mean here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting by date & time in descending order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511882/sorting-by-date-time-in-descending-order)

Comment: I mean descending order..

so the results would first show this day's values and then from the future to past results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM 
  ...
ORDER BY IF(DATE(datefield=CURRENT_DATE()),0,1), datefield DESC
```

**Edit**

Added the `DESC` to the `ORDER BY` after the 3rd comment to the OQ

Comment: @Strawberry ... which is perfectly productive, but much less instructive.

Comment: will it still apply if I put datefield in descending order?

Comment: @Jay-arBuño Did u try?

Comment: @Strawberry it sorted by today first, but future results are not shown