# MYSQL Order by Clause is not working on Currencies table when column name is Date and column Data Type is Date and time

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have database table for currencies. I update currencies on daily basis by using google finance API along with date and time. My column name is **Date** and data type is **datetime**

I want to fetch currency rate of Dollar which is last updated on database on basis of date, instead of id of table.

Below queries shows always same result.

```
SELECT * FROM `currencyrates` WHERE CurrencyCode='USD' AND Rate > 0  ORDER BY 'Date' ASC

SELECT * FROM `currencyrates` WHERE CurrencyCode='USD' AND Rate > 0  ORDER BY 'Date' DESC
```

[image]

It always shows records from 2015, instead it should show record of 2019 first because records exits in database i checked it by sorting in my SQL tool (SQLyog).

[image]

Comment: And note that 'Date' is a string constant. Perhaps you were thinking of \`Date\`

Comment: @Strawberry Let me try with it.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes it worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*SELECT * FROM `currencyrates` WHERE CurrencyCode='USD' AND Rate >= 0  ORDER BY 'Date' ASC

SELECT * FROM `currencyrates` WHERE CurrencyCode='USD' AND Rate >= 0  ORDER BY 'Date' DESC*

Comment: 'Date' is a string constant.

Comment: Above queries always shows same result i check your query in which you mention order by desc

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511882/sorting-by-date-time-in-descending-order

Comment: Adding string constant solved my problem ORDER BY `Date` it is not same as ORDER BY 'Date'. I was using column as string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511882/sorting-by-date-time-in-descending-order?noredirect=1&lq=1